# Dynamic db in dependency injection

Tags: database, symfony, dependency-injection, entitymanager

I implement multiple db concept in symfony 2.0 . Now i need to get the entity manager as dynamically in myservice.php file in the concept of dependence injection . How can i call this entity manager ?

services.xml :

```
        <container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services                                 http://symfony.com     /schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

<services>
    <service id="my_service" class="Traxcrm\SalesBundle\Services\MyService">
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine" />
    </service>
 </services>

 </container>
```

mysevice.php

```
class MyService  {

private $doctrine;

public function __construct(Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry $doctrine)
{

    $this->doctrine = $doctrine;            

}
class MyService {

 private $doctrine;

 public function __construct(Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry $doctrine) {

     $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
 }

 public function getUserDetails($id) {

     $query = $this->doctrine->getEntityManager('Test')->createQuery("SELECT        p            FROM        TraxcrmSigninBundle:Tblallusers p where p.id=$id");
    $userDetails = $query->getArrayResult();

    return $userDetails;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup a service and inject doctrine :

Service Definition (services.yml or config.yml):

```
services:
    service_name:
        class: <namespace>myservice.php
        arguments: ['@doctrine']
```

or xml :

```
<services>
    <service id="service_name" class="<namespace>myservice.php">
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

then setup your class to accept the doctrine object passed

```
public class myservice {

   private $doctrine;

   public function __construct(Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry $doctrine) {
       $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
   }

   public function aFunction() {
       $em = $this->doctrine->getEntityManager('<name>')......
   }
}
```

Comment: I am using services.xml file not services.yml

Comment: @user1650898 i have updated my answer - but i suggest you read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) for more details on using the Service Container

Comment: I got the error : Notice: Undefined property: Traxcrm\CustomerCareBundle\Services\MyService::$container in /var/www/html/traxerpconstruction/src/Traxcrm/CustomerCareBundle/Services/MyService.php line 23

Comment: can you add your source to your question - including the MyService.php file and the services.xml

Comment: services.xml : <?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

   <services>
            <service id="my_service" class="Traxcrm\SalesBundle\Services\MyService.php">
                <argument type="service" id="doctrine" />
            </service>
    </services>    
</container>

Comment: myservice.php : class MyService  {
    
    private $doctrine;

    public function __construct(Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry $doctrine)
    {
        
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;            
            
    }

    public function getUserDetails($id)
    {

        $query = $this->doctrine->getEntityManager('Test')->createQuery("SELECT p FROM TraxcrmSigninBundle:Tblallusers p where p.id=$id");
        $userDetails = $query->getArrayResult();

        return $userDetails;

    }
}

Comment: @user1650898 everything looks to be OK ... cannot see where the error is - make sure your namespaces are correct though

Comment: I edited the question..kindly check my question and tell me the answer